# Invalid character error in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying out a simple trigger in PL/SQL. The trigger is supposed to maintain a log table. The log will record the system date and the number of rows affected.

This was my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREATELOGUPDATE
AFTER DELETE ON TREATMENT_HISTORY
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO LOG VALUES(SYSDATE,SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

This is just a statement level trigger. It gives me a missing character error at line 2.

I have one more question.

Is SQL%ROWCOUNT correctly used to count the number of rows affected by the last statement?

Comment: Why do you need a trigger for this? Shouldn't it go in the code that's deleting from the table or do you have multiple avenues in which to do this?

Comment: I need to do it as an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CREATELOGUPDATE
AFTER DELETE ON TREATMENT_HISTORY
DECLARE
 rows_number NUMBER;
BEGIN
 rows_number:=SQL%ROWCOUNT;
 INSERT INTO LOG VALUES(SYSDATE,rows_number);
END;
```

will make your trigger to be created without an error. However, it will not work as intended as SQL%ROWCOUNT is not right to use here and will permanently return NULL.

One possible solution can be to create a ROW level trigger and increment some number stored in log table for each row affected.